# How to update object inside fromJS with ImmutableJS?

Tags: immutable.js

Hello I'm new to ImmutableJs. I want to update an particular object in ImmutableJs array.

Here is my array

```
const todos = Immutable.fromJS([{
               text: 'ADDED TODO',
               id: 0,
               todo:[]
            },
            {
               text: 'DELETED TODO',
               id: 1,
               todo:[]
             },
             {
               text: 'DELETED TODO',
               id: 1,
               todo:[]
             }]);
```

Now I want to push an object in the second object where id is 1 inside todo empty array.

Can anyone suggest the way to do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list is ordered by `id`, you can just do this:

```
const newTodos = todos.update(
    1,
    map => map.update(
        "todo",
        list => list.push("item")
    )
);
```

First `update` find the `Map` with corresponding index and apply it to a function. Second `update` is similar, it finds the key with `todo` and apply it to another function. Then you simply push whatever item into your `todo` list and it's done.

If you are not sure that `id` is corresponded to the index, replace `1` with `findIndex` as follow.

```
todos.findIndex(todo => todo.get("id") === 1),
```